# Spanish Wikipedia processing using Gensim

Tags: python, wikipedia, gensim, word2vec

I want to process the wikipedia using `gensim.corpora.wikicorpus`. My final objective is to train a [Word2Vec](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/) Model from it.

I have it working but I have a problem with the accented vowels of Spanish: á, é, í, ó, ú.

I want to normalize them to a, e, i, o, u.

I have seem that there is a [deaccent](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/utils.html#gensim.utils.deaccent) function in gensim but I dwould like to apply it directly while I am building the corpus. Can this be done?

Here is a working example:

```
from gensim.corpora import WikiCorpus
from gensim.models.word2vec import  Word2Vec
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s',
                level=logging.INFO)

# I would like to include here the normalization
corpus = WikiCorpus('/Users/jesusfbes/Desktop/eswiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2', dictionary=False)


max_sentence = -1


def generate_lines():
    for index, text in enumerate(corpus.get_texts()):
        if index < max_sentence or max_sentence == -1:
            yield text
        else:
            break

model = Word2Vec(size=400, window=5, min_count=5)
model.build_vocab(generate_lines())
model.train(generate_lines(), chunksize=500)

model.save('mymodel')
```

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as accepted (grey tick mark on the left of the answer) and upvoting it if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you should do is something along these lines:

```
from gensim.utils import deaccent

def generate_lines():
    for index, text in enumerate(corpus.get_texts()):
        if index < max_sentence or max_sentence == -1:
            yield deaccent(text)
        else:
            break
```

I would also store the results of the call to generate_lines() for efficiency as long as you have enough RAM to store the results and reuse them in both model.build_vocab() and model.train() calls.